# problems with sendmail configuration

Tags: configuration, email, sendmail

I want to configure sendmail on my system so that every user can send email.
i followed the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu but get

```
Jan 25 19:12:39 regDesktopHome sendmail[32386]: t0Q3CdAt032386: from=root, size=39, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201501260312.t0Q3CdAt032386@regDesktopHome.lan>, relay=root@localhost
Jan 25 19:12:39 regDesktopHome sm-mta[32387]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): hash map "access": unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db: Permission denied
Jan 25 19:12:39 regDesktopHome sm-mta[32387]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=localhost, arg2=127.0.0.1, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1], reject=451 4.3.0 Temporary system failure. Please try again later.
Jan 25 19:12:39 regDesktopHome sendmail[32386]: t0Q3CdAt032386: to=ron.eggler@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30039, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: 451 4.3.0 Temporary system failure. Please try again later.
Jan 25 19:14:20 regDesktopHome sendmail[32455]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(ron): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 0: cannot open: Permission denied
```

in `/var/log/mail.log` when I execute `echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail ron.eggler@gmail.com` why do I get a `Temporary system failure` error?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that it can't open /etc/mail/sendmail.cf due to permissions. Can you try `sudo cat /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` just to see if you can read it as sudo? perhaps also sendmail is trying as a different user. Also, try just this: `echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | sendmail ron.eggler@gmail.com`